# Collection.find({_id: { $in : myArray }} doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I feel like a ditz for asking this, because I've been using Mongo for a few years now, and this seems like it should be an easy and simple query.  But I can't seem to query an array of records for the life of me.  Here's the basic code:

So, I've been creating a collection of document IDs like so:

```
\\first, I create a collection of document ids  
Rooms.update(Session.get('selected_room'), {$addToSet: {reservations: this._id}})

\\then, I pull the array of ids like so
var reservationsList = Rooms.findOne(selectedRoomId).reservations;

\\ when I inspect, everything is fine and it produces an array of document ids 
console.log(JSON.stringify(reservationList)

["Rym8yc4GbNmnNcsmx","msLcBMRQxBdjgLddE","XG2z4qQRD5j4ERBca"]
```

So, everything is working fine up until that point.  Here's where I start running into problems:

```
//doesn't work
var cursor = Schedule.find({'_id': {$in: reservationsList }});

//doesn't work
var cursor = Schedule.find({_id: {$in: reservationsList }});

//doesn't work
var cursor = Schedule.find({_id: reservationsList });

//doesn't work
var cursor = Schedule.find(reservationsList);
```

All of these result in a TypeError{}.

Any ideas on how to do this query?  All I want to do is pass in an array of _ids to my find() function, and get a cursor of the documents back.

Edit:  The following *does* work, so I know it's not an issue with MongoId wrappers and the like:

```
record = Schedule.findOne({'_id': reservationsList[0]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bah.  Writing out the question let me organize my thoughts enough that I figured it out as soon as I finished and posted the question.  I forgot .fetch() like so:

```
Schedule.find({_id: {$in: reservationsList }}).fetch();
```